# Updating a M2M relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Is there a way to directly update a M2M relationship, other than by deleting the old_object & then adding a new_object?

This is what I currently have to add a new object --

```
if 'Add School' in request.POST.values():     
    form = EducationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid and request.POST['school']:
         school_object = form.save()
         profile.educations.add(school_object)
         profile.save()
         return redirect('edit_education')
```

And this what I'm trying to do --

```
if 'Save Changes' in request.POST.values():
    form = EducationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid and request.POST['school']:
         new_school_object = form.save(commit=False)    
         old_school_object = Education.objects.get(id = request.post['id']) 
         # profile.educations.get(old_school_object).update(new_school_object) # ?
         profile.save()
         return redirect('edit_education')
```

And here are my models --

```
class Education(models.Model):
    school = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class_year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True, choices=YEAR)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    ...
    educations = models.ManyToManyField(Education)
```

Comment: Can you post your models as well?

Comment: @Udi, I've updated to include the models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Education` is probably something personal to one `UserProfile`, so you should use a `ForeignKey` instead of M2M:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    ...

class Education(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class_year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True, choices=YEAR)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

(and optionally use model formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets )

If `Education` is actually shared between users, it should not be possible for one user to modify/update it - since other users are using it as well! consider users Alice and Bob, both learning for BSc in USC class of 2011.  If Alice changes this to MA, Bob education will change as well!

Another tip:  In your templates use `<input type="submit" name="save" value="..."/>` and `<input type="submit" name="add" value="..."/>` and in your `if`s check for the keys "save" or "add" instead.

Comment: @ Udi, thanks for the response. What if the user has multiple entries for his education, though? For example, if he has an undergrad school and then a graduate school. It would never be shared between users, but a user may have multiple entries. Also, did you attend USC?

Comment: @David542, A ForeignKey creates a many-to-one relationship.  Any UserProfile can have zero or more Education instances. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey . I did not attend USC, but HUJI.